# Cant install mediapipe library for Python: OSError, access denied

Tags: python, mediapipe

I tried installing on admin but that doesnt work either.

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post your output as code-formatted text.

Comment: ...and what is the actual problem? It seems to have installed properly.

Comment: see the red text? it's hard to see. it says that it couldn't update `cv2.pyd`. there's probably some other script still running which uses opencv from python.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Well, now I see. I'd like to use the opportunity to emphasize my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, in cmd(Admin) not powershell you can try.

```
python -m pip install mediapipe
```

Comment: installing anything as admin is usually a bad idea. don't override the safeties. figure out what's wrong instead, and fix the issue.